# Using CSS to make image size 100% to height of container

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have looked around reading solution after solution and trying all kinds of things but never getting this to work right...

I want the image to end up being dynamically resized based on the current height of the browser window.  Currently using the code below the image is the original height and ends up being LARGER than the browser window causing a vertical scrollbar to appear.

**Note: Please keep in mind I want this accomplished using the same amount of of tables and cells.  Please do not give me a single table solution.**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body
      {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      }
      table.one
      {
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      table.two
      {
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      img
      {
        max-height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="one" cellpadding=0>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table class="two" cellpadding=0>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img src="myimage.jpg">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should really stop using tables in HTML. Check out this simple link why http://blog.silktide.com/2011/04/why-you-shouldnt-use-tables-for-layout-ever/

Comment: What is the prupose of this project?  What is the image being used for?  Is it a background image?  Is this for an email project?  If not you should shy away from tables.

Comment: The reason for using this layout is for compatibility reasons. I know it has to be possible using the layout that I have. Instead of telling me I'm doing something wrong why not actually contribute some knowledge and show me some code of how YOU think it should be done.  There is nothing worse then a useless comment. To answer hungerstar, it's to display an image in the center of the screen, NOT a background image. This will be used to display something on a local machine with NO webserver involved.  The user could have any type of browser (including a TV browser such as the Samsung Smart TV).

Comment: So the primary issue is centering the image vertically and horizontally while taking up the full height?

Comment: Correct hungerstar.  I just need the image to show up in the middle of the page.  The page (browser) is currently a 800x600 window and the image size is 600x1200.  The image needs to be in the center of the page and needs to be no larger than the browser window.

Comment: @ArvoBowen I took a couple shots at it but I couldn't get it to go with the table structure which you require.  I Could totaly do it without them.  Just couldn't find the right mix for the tables. The main issue you're up against is the way tables are rendered with content.

Comment: Thanks for trying hungerstar!  I don't know if everyone has the impression I don't want to use css..  That's not the case!  I would welcome css as long as all attributes are support well and examples are given to obtain the same results.  But NO javascript.  ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35202/discussion-between-hungerstar-and-arvo-bowen)

Comment: I added a test code that is just text, should be the same across browsers.

Comment: Funny thing, the more and more I look into it, I find that people use css to position but use atribs such as display: table and display: table-row...  Why use css to position in the first place if you're just going to use the equivalent of tables?

Answer (score 8):

You can use viewport units to resize based on the size of the browser window.

```
img {
    max-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: As neat as this is and how excited to see that it worked in my browser (chrome) I looked into it and http://caniuse.com/viewport-units says that android would not suport it... :(  Still an upvote for a great tip!

Comment: Interesting. Chrome for Android supports it, didn't realize the stock Android browser doesn't. What percentage of Android devices still ship with the stock browser? My only experience is my Nexus 7, which does not have the stock browser but did ship with Chrome.

Comment: I use chrome too...  hehe  But just because I do something I can't expect everyone else to do the same.  :(

Answer (score 1):

Add `img {display:block;}`. This should get rid of a few pixels at the bottom.

Also `td {padding:0;}` will do the same thing as `cellpadding=0` but is a HTML5 solution.

**Edit**: Try this out then, it appears to be the same for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {margin:0; padding:0;}
        table {border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0;}
        td {padding:0;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="background:#888;">
        <tr style="background:#f88;">
            <td style="background:#8f8;">I should</td>
            <td style="background:#88f;">look the</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background:#ff8;">
            <td style="background:#8ff;">same across<td/>
            <td style="background:#f8f;">different browsers</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips asimes but using td {padding:0;} does NOT give the same results in chrome.  I tried that first thing and noticed a 1px gap around the image in my example.  Adding cellpadding=0 fixed the issue.

Comment: Added an edit, in my experience this works. The only difference I see across browsers is the default font-size.

Answer (score -3):

Try this with Jquery imagescale:

```
<img id="img1" src="myimage.jpg">

    $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $('#img1').imgscale({ 
        parent : '.parentcontainer',
        fade : 1000 
      }); 
    });
```

keep remember define your parent container width and height first as:

```
.parentcontainer {
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: Jquery all the things. http://zarjay.net/2012/03/20/jquery-is-really-great-and-does-all-things/

Comment: Many loves in-hand solution to their problem. Otherwise they put -1

Comment: Ashwin, Don't worry. I was also downvoted the same way for providing a jQuery solution for a question that really did not need it. I learnt it the hard way. Don't be disheartened. Just say "This too shall pass"

Comment: No prob. that wasn't for you. That was for user as they always need a full complete solution without loosing their code comfort a bit, even it is good for them.

Comment: Sorry I had to downvote too.  This solution should not use any javascript of any type.  The user's browser should also not need access to the internet as well because it's on the local machine.  Jquery has it's place just not here.  ;)

Comment: Without jquery it will always have bugs, according to your approach image will always overflow slightly. @ArvoBowen

Comment: So your saying that before jQuery came along it was never possible to display an image the the height of the browser window?  I didn't want to vote up your comment but I wish there was a like button ...  It made me laugh a bit.  :-)

Comment: 'Never' word don't suite to programming. I was just worry about cross-browser support of css. In case of cross-browsing producing same results over all, I believe in jquery/javascript.

Comment: Understood.  Thanks Ashwin for the input.  ;)