# splash screen with css height 100% not work

Tags: css

I have splash screen like this.

HTML

```
<div id="spalsh">
  <span> <img src="{% static 'dbexplorer/img/loading.gif' %}" style="height: 100px;" > </span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#spalsh{
    width: 98%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(252, 252, 252, 0.67);
    z-index: 10000;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#spalsh span{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 60px;
}
```

If page height increase dynamically then splash screen not cover full height. I want to cover full height of page. Is there any solution with PURE CSS without JS?

Adding a image :
[image: splash]

Comment: why not trying to add height:100% to the span too?

Comment: You should image height 100%.
See here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164227/using-css-to-make-image-size-100-to-height-of-container][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164227/using-css-to-make-image-size-100-to-height-of-container

Comment: Tried, No Success..:)

Comment: Set `min-height: 100%;` instead of `height: 100%;` to `#spalsh` - http://jsfiddle.net/5eh1fh61/

Comment: @MaryMelody Nope, that dosent help.

Comment: @MaryMelody My page height increase dynamically. your solution works for static fix height page.

Comment: @MaryMelody Try this Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5eh1fh61/9/

Comment: @MaryMelody First Click on Show/Hide splash button. show splash will come and it will cover full screen. now press second button that will add some text to page.. Now click on show/Hide button. it will cover only half of page. if you scroll then you can see at bottom side splash screen is not visible. Now I want to cover full screen always.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to make a screen-covering splash image?

Try giving the div `spalsh` (shouldn't this be **splash**?) a background-covering background.

```
.spalsh { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

[Tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

This should make the background image in `spalsh` resize with the browser.

Also, I would really rename it to `splash`

Comment: Sorry for my naming.. ;)
My image is very small loading gif. Your solution makes it full height gif. Even after using your solution its not covering full page height.

Comment: Could you maybe set up a JSfiddle or host it somewhere, so we can play with your code?

Comment: The splash does resize with me in that fiddle. Could you explain what doesn't work as you want it?

Comment: First Click on Show/Hide splash button. show splash will come and it will cover full screen. now press second button that will add some text to page.. Now click on show/Hide button. it will cover only half of page. if you scroll then you can see at bottom side splash screen is not visible. Now I want to cover full screen always. –

Comment: I really can't replicate your problem. See my screenshot: http://i57.tinypic.com/2i6khy.png

Comment: Please dont remove scroll. or you can increase the content size tooooo much.. check this image. http://i57.tinypic.com/1ilp54.jpg

Comment: Have you tried in different browsers? I have not removed anything, I'm just running your Fiddle.